# Numerical id should work with with /posts/ as it does with /questions/

Tags: feature-request, questions

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a question in search result listings.
2. Click the search result to go to the question.
3. Click edit to improve the question.
4. After deciding to read comments/answers/not presently edit, remove "/edit" from the URL, expecting to go back to the question.

Expected result:
 5. Return to question page.

Actual result:
5. 404 Page Not Found error.

If a 404 will be returned, at least a suggestion to change "posts" to "questions" in the URL would be helpful, but it seems like this could be automatically attempted and the user automatically redirected away from 404 to what they were apparently looking for.

As discussed in a now-deleted answer, "There are PLENTY of routes that being with or contain `/posts/` - just not the one used to display questions and answers." Given all the routes that do contain `/posts/`, it seems reasonable to expect `/posts/<id>` to display the post with the given ID.

Comment: Rule of thumb: we should not manually mess with the URL, and if we do, we should not be surprised if it's "not working".

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons for manually messing with URLs - e.g. shortening for character-limited contexts or removing irrelevant parameters - and testing to see if they work.  When it should be clear what the intended target is, it would be nice to see the URL reach that page.

Comment: for shortening there is the `/q/{id}` route.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Unless messing with the URL is the only way to get to an information which is in principle public...

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons to "mess" with a URL. Not knowing what you're doing isn't one of them though.

Comment: @yo' like timeline, agreed. But still, it's not a bug when unsupported and unlinked URL is leading to a different place than we expect.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this was changed to feature request before your comment was posted.